# Making status bar text bigger in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-customization

I just installed QGIS 3.4 and the text in the status bar is way smaller than it used to be.

Is there a way of increasing the text size?

See comparison below:

QGIS 3.4
[image]

QGIS 3.2
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to `Settings -> Options -> General -> Font` and change the font size from 8 to 10 or the size you like. Then restart QGIS 3.4.

[image]